# AngularJS - filter for field in child- object

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use this ngRepeat in my AngularJS application:

```
data-ng-repeat="communicationUserConnection in vm.communicationUserConnections | filter:searchString | filter:{project:vm.selectedProject}"
```

**vm.communicationUserConnections** objects contains a property **project** and I will filter of projects (show all communicationUserConnections where communicationUserConnection#project == vm.selectedProject). I have tried it like this

```
... | filter:{project:vm.selectedProject}
```

but it does not work. I would need any hint of doing this.

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: try `| filter:{project:vm.selectedProject}:true`

Comment: Sorrily it is not working - nothing is shown

Comment: can you create demo?

Comment: | filter: {project: {name: vm.selectedProject.name}} this is the solution

Comment: May I suggest you create a function in your controller that your filter calls to make that more clear. Also easier to test that way.